# why flowtype does not show error in this sample code?

Tags: flowtype

I just upgraded to flow type 0.78, the following code is not showing any errror, why?

```
//@flow
var fs = require('fs')

var m = fs.readFileSync(123)
```

Comment: Did it use to show an error for that code? What error did it show? And when you upgraded “flow type”, you mean you updated the `flow-bin` package, right? What version were you using before?